# angularjs binding from view to controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ngmodel

I want to do a two way data-binding from my view to controller. is it possible to do it using ng-model? it displays undefined in the controller though.

My code is something like:

```
<span ng-model="xyz">${user.group}</span>
```

and in my controller:
    console.log($scope.xyz); //returns undefined.

What is the use of ng-model if I cannot use it this way?
Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: What is ${user.group}?

Comment: it is coming from a java class when the view is loaded.

Comment: Well, you're trying to get the text of a span.  It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Can u please suggest what to do then?

Comment: Two way binding works like this: <input type="text" ng-model="name">{{name}}

Comment: well, yeah, i know how two way binding works. But I want to be able to use data in ${user.group} in my controller. is there anyway i can do it?

Comment: Usually the controller assigns json to the scope model.  So in your controller you would have $scope.user = {group:'whatever'};  But without seeing more code its hard to provide more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the ng-model must be bound to an actual value.  Spans do not have a value associated to them like inputs do so your $scope.xyz would never be set unless you set it in the scope.  Even after that it would not do anything with the span.  You also need double {{ and }} around everything, not single {}.  You also do not need the $ symbol in the html.

Try :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="xyz" /> <span> {{xyz}} </span>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i got it working using span element. like this:    <span ng-bind="getGp('${user.studentGroup}')"></span>

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, I was missing to pass the argument to this function as a string, I simply had to do this using ng-bind on span tag like this:
    ng-bind="getGp('${user.group}')"

Thanks everyone.